# Context specific MIDI routing (Ableton)

Tags: midi, ableton, controller

Simplistically, I have a MIDI controller with a keyboard, and 8 knobs.

If I record-arm one track, the keyboard will play through that track.
If I MIDI-learn a hardware knob to a software function, it will continue to control that software function, even after I record-arm another track.

In this example, the MIDI keyboard is context/track aware, while the knob sticks to the specifically configured parameter.

I want the active track to have its own assignment of midi functions, so that I can change active tracks, and have an entirely different set of functions mapped to my controller.

howtf.

Comment: Can you give us the moel of your controller and your Live version please? Thx

Comment: Novation Launchkey 49, and Live 9.  The Launchkey has a track selector switch, that got me thinking about this.  If I could control individual chains within tracks, that would be great too.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: I've had a few suggestions that I'm going to try out.  Don't worry, I won't DenverCoder9 this thread ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Suit download MAX4Live.

Under Live API, the parameter called selected Device is what you need to tap.

So essentially you'll be making one max patch to which u'll hard map your controller, while this max patch is aware and will control the selected device. so turning the knob on your controller will turn the knob of max patch as well the selected device.

A sample Code I use to control 'n' number of turnado knobs

```
----------begin_max5_patcher----------
939.3ocyX90jZBCD.+Y8SACSej5PRPD5asS+VbSGmHjSyMXhCIXuqctu6M+Q
9imAEsmb2CJXxR1M+1M6txemNweE+Yhv26adO3MYxemNYhYH8.SN76I9awOm
UfEFw7Kn6IyDEzbRoefc9MTlzL2OoYRrj2LAlw3pAnblyo2iKY3sDmysCKyT
q65kkjLo09RBmEF3AhR0Wlmn+NELKz6W0ORIQPXs5CbXbV0VdkrfHMa.3gQk
kzLdgRgl0VszIwvEyCT2kj.QyQJMYTWWEfKUlqjTtjvvqJHcUhj7r7ZWuG4Y
UhU7REJO9QSSBQoA8cWyya2UxW1QrOouefm+iEbrBX0xrkmWUXPRGUXrjvYn
nzPnYIOdcUnwkUM..0wCzwwgzxA6wqYCktVMQyMQM7UO80E9s9YJq1MCZ2KG
s0GzpKv6I4KwRMHpjj16DGNXb3jgNDtnhverd35w6FqTvYq6KL+HAEa3kxAI
YsKOzwbaUmVM.XlqYoLpjhKNM.1kTMDqFLGITkRHg7k9Wk1S+KOcWYE+0oSa
uX990oACLQjJPW4wOS9BPrISALJ1D5YydjzwM6NwfqS4gMmXYRA8O1sbXMg0
1EcqxV5hceUvX8fsRdxQV6wU041UX1ZeWw2w9cTdCH+doxA48CdQt6v+a.nL
xuU5yuSBMyvJVTx8PgmgznPyoa.vdRJ7RnFbdbdBj5kMQ2BafuerQ47xMFW+
rAZC7hhlMebQSzXE2rkHD30jSfCM2K7rfIUiD3745KGNdF+tAF2PIdrBX5CJ
lBF5DByg.vhyfmTSVKTpshIbLnCD8QSm0DomgP0yTPYjLdks+R3knEbQTarD
bwclVfO5jO5NwUSngvEqBhPv6StYmrAjdSr4n1ur6ryz60xcjRAUHIrLRStq
aqWh9hGU7bimlyKEpHS7tcb0e0QYa4j8zLhWSqBBuTmQrnKVW.DgrkNMtGz8
1uD9YHlUS0KWwDFFOrHVz0RlfCebQHzGcUSQcJPuu.t1rf0c7lLhoA+uyBZV
TyV7MuGByFTO9wTTvqJypMoC+APu1sXNQHorlWBvCMMQ2QlMz7bBqai84Tgt
Wey1Jzo2bnVS7.rFvnYM5t.un4D84xbzIoFK64yk4nR93AtjyJ9Hgt2lyEoS
5nYNPvPsmwwa8FU41dfnQiOuIP0s8fFO7bO8V1hFpFx1q6AztlFKQUj8I665
KNXp8svX+ooXmeopwsZ4AFk3iKUkQkpZnUk1ZWOmD6OUqnWm9O.wT2lV
-----------end_max5_patcher-----------
```

Comment: Not so simple, but looks effective, and better than my answer of, "I don't think you can do that".

Comment: That's some mighty obfuscated code.  Curious how that was generated.

Comment: @derjur Copy Compressed inside MAX/MSP

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing for this is a bit hacky, but it works great.

I counted how many synth plugins I needed to run at any given time.  In my case, it's 3.  I counted how many midi knobs I had to use, and it's 8.

I created 3 tracks, and inside each track I created a chain.  Each chain runs solo (using the chain selector), while all instruments in the chain have their knobs associated to them.

While this means that each knob is linked to several synths at a time, only the relevant synth (selected by the active chain) is playing at any one time.